# Phantom mobile app fails silently when interacting with new Mobile Wallet Adapter?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, phantom, mobile-wallet-adapter

I upgraded to latest version of https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter in order to use the Mobile Wallet Adapter in Android devices. AS the time of writing this, the only wallets that have integrated this are Solflare and Phantom.

Everything went smoothly when testing the wallet-adapter-react-ui on a website running locally and exposed through ngrok when using Solflare, but when testing Phantom it just failed without any message, the transaction request never reached phantom wallet, and the app just crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking in discord about this, and with help I checked again and realized I was using devnet in the website but mainnet in phantom app,and that was perfectly working with Solflare as it seems they detect the cluster in use, but Phantom does not. So if you're reading this , double check your network in the website and the network you're using in de mobile app. Maybe phantom should also try to detect that and or send a better error message?

Hope this helps.